# raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}") in Django API call

Tags: python, django, api

I am trying to call an API in Django and I have the following code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def intasend_webhook_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        payload = request.body
        response = requests.get(payload)
        intasend_body = json.loads(response)
        api_ref = intasend_body.get("api_ref")
        state = intasend_body.get("state")

        order = Order.objects.get(pk=api_ref)
        if state == "FAILED":
             order.payment_status == "Unpaid"
             order.save()
        elif state == "COMPLETED":
             order.payment_status == "Paid"
             order.save()
            

    return JsonResponse('success', safe=False)
```

What I am basically doing is that I want to change the order status to "Paid" once the payment collection event is called and returns "COMPLETED" status. When I try to perform a test transaction, I get the following error in my shell:

```
raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '{"invoice_id": "VYBP5OQ", "state": "FAILED", "provider": "CARD-PAYMENT", "charges": "0.00", "net_amount": "84.00", "currency": "USD", "value": "84.00", "account": "email@outlook.com", "api_ref": "2", "mpesa_reference": null, "host": "http://127.0.0.1:8000", "failed_reason": null, "failed_code": null, "failed_code_link": "https://intasend.com/troubleshooting", "created_at": "2022-10-28T11:55:40.755353+03:00", "updated_at": "2022-10-28T11:55:54.504547+03:00", "challenge": "123"}'
[28/Oct/2022 11:55:54] "POST /webhooks/intasend/ HTTP/1.1" 500 97938
```

I am one year into django programming and I don't know much about APIs. For example, the response above needs to indicate the order is "Unpaid" because the "state" of the transaction is "FAILED"

Anyone who can help me to proceed from here please?

I expected the transaction to be seamless but it seems the InvalidSCHEMA error is preventing everything to happen as expected